Configuring haproxy to use an outgoing squid
I've got a use case for a reverse proxy, like haproxy. However, the target server for that reverse proxy is available only via an outgoing proxy (squid). So the overall connection looks like this:
Client -> haproxy -> Squid -> Target
I tried a config like this in haproxy, but it doesn't work:
backend mytarget
    http-request set-header Host mytarget:9876
    server squid mysquid:3128 send-proxy

It seems that haproxy doesn't replace the Host. Am I missing something in the config? or maybe haproxy is a wrong tool for what I need? If so, what should it be?
